# Check which app is set as home activity

Tags: android, homescreen

What API call can determine which app is Home App? Also whether it is set to just once, or always?  I assume you cannot change this setting via api, but is there a way to check app has been set set?

Comment: explain what do you mean under home app?

Comment: Did my answer help you, @MuayThai? If so, please accept it. If not, let me now what's troubling you.

Comment: did you got solution for android 30?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an intent to launch the home activity (`ACTION_MAIN` and `CATEGORY_HOME`) and then check what the system decides to use for it:

```
// Intent to launch home activity.
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
final ResolveInfo info = pm.resolveActivity(i, 0);
Toast.makeText(this, "Homescreen application: " + pm.getApplicationLabel(info.activityInfo.applicationInfo), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

In my case this shows "Home application: Nova Launcher". This is the home activity that is set to "always". There is no way to check for which application the user pressed the "once" button, since that only affects the activity that is started on that moment (it is not stored).

Comment: This is  not working with android API 30, upto 29 its working, in Android 30 its giving all list of home apps.

Answer (score 0):

With this code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
for(final ResolveInfo resolveInfo:pm.queryIntentActivities(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN).addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME), PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY))
{  
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Homescreen application: " + pm.getApplicationLabel(resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

you can get all the homescreen apps